# Extract numbers and find missing numbers in filenames

Tags: bash

In bash, I have a folder containing some subfolders and files as

```
folder1/
folder2/
script_1.ext
script_2.ext
script_4.ext
...
script_N.ext
```

, where N is a known large number. I would like to know which numbers are missing in the filenames. 
I am trying to come up with simple codes that I can extract numbers from the filenames (in the example, it is 1,2,4,...,N) and find missing numbers in 1:N (for example, 3).

I am very new to bash scripts. I tried to find similar questions and answers but I couldn't.
Any input will be appreciated!

ps. I have tried

```
ls -1 | sed 's/script_//' | sed 's/.ext//'
```

and successfully extracted the numbers, but I am unsure how to save those numbers and compare with 1,...,N to obtain missing numbers.

Comment: So if a number is missing the `N` is there?, what is `1:N` ?

Comment: For 1:N, I meant {1,...,N}. Basically I want to find numbers in 1,...,N for a known N, that do not exist in the filenames.

Comment: Are all files in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I want to find numbers in 1,...,N for a **known N**, that do not exist in the filenames.

Presuming `file_` and `.ext` are common patterns among your files; loop through 1 to N, build filenames, check their existence and report if they're missing.

```
N=10 # known N
for ((i=1;i<=N;i++)); do
  f=file_$i.ext
  if [ ! -f "$f" ]; then
    printf '%s is missing\n' "$f"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the numbers is fine. Comparing with 1..N can be done as follows.

Assuming the numbers are in range 1..100:

```sh
diff <(ls -1 | sed 's/script_//' | sed 's/.ext//' | sort -n) <(echo "$(seq 1 100)") | sed -n 's/> //p'
```

Or if the upper bound is below 10:

```sh
diff <(ls -1 | sed 's/script_//' | sed 's/.ext//') <(echo "$(seq 1 9)") | sed -n 's/> //p'
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @oguzismail OK, it's not safe. However, the OP stated that he successfully extracted the numbers in this way.

Comment: It's a tradition to post that link to answers involving parsing of ls :D I'm not saying your answer is wrong or bad or something